# Format bytes as hex string

Tags: python

I have a RFID reader. The physical interface is compatible with the RS – 232 specifications.
1start bit、8 data bits、1 stop bit、no even odd check.. Here is the code i use to run the reader and read the UHF RFID tags

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM8', baudrate=115200, timeout=0.01)
ba_antenna_set_1 = b'\xA0\x04\x01\x74\x00\xE7'
ba_antenna_set_2 = b'\xA0\x04\x01\x74\x10\xD7'
ba_inventory =  b'\xA0\x04\x01\x89\x01\xD1' 
ser.write(ba_antenna_set_1);
ser.write(ba_antenna_set_2);
while True:
    ser.write(ba_inventory);
    if ser.in_waiting > 0:    
        data = ser.readline()
        print(data)
```

When I run this code, I get an output like this:

b'\xa0\x04\x01t\x10\xd7'
b'\xa0\x13\x01\x89t0\x000\x083\xb2\xdd\xd9\x01@\x00\x00\x00\x00M\xbe'
b'\xa0\n'
b'\x01\x89\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\xbb'
b'\xa0\x13\x01\x89\x040\x000\x083\xb2\xdd\xd9\x01@\x00\x00\x00\x00N-'

I want my output to be as below and I need help with this

'A0 04 01 74 00 E7'
'A0 04 01 74 10 D7'
'A0 04 01 89 01 D1'
'A0 13 01 89 24 30 00 30 08 33 B2 DD D9 01 40 00 00 00 00 50 0B'
'A0 0A 01 89 00 00 11 00 00 00 01 BA'

Comment: First step is the method `hex()` of `bytes`. Then some formatting remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data=ser.readline()` returns a `bytes` array, so you want that converted to a hex string. There is a built in method for that, `.hex()`, which returns a hex string with no spaces by default, but you can specify a space, and you can use `.upper()` to convert the a-f characters to upper case.

```
datastring = data.hex(' ').upper()
print(datastring)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```py
data = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This makes no sense here.